# getting GMSServicesException error

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am trying to execute my project, while going to home page itself am getting this error and app is crashing

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources''

Answer (score 3):

Please select project name from Xcode, select "Targets", select Build Phases . Open "Copy Bundle Resources" , then click on "+" button. It will open an windows containing the name of bundle file. Click on ADD to add in your bundle resources.

Steps:-

ProjectName -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy bundle Resources -> Click on "+" Button -> Add the specified file

Answer (score 2):

If you installed it via Cocoapods, the only solution I have found so far is removing it from the podfile, updating pods, then putting in back in the podfile and updating again.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was cleaning my project.
Go to Product->Clean. (Shift-Command-K)

Answer (score 0):

For those who use **CocoaPods** to install **GoogleMaps**, you can simply clean the project and build.

From the top menu in Xcode, click **Product** > **Clean** or **SHIFT + CMD + K**